# Tables aren’t showing rows past a certain row?

Tags: html

I just have a simple table that displays information about musical releases, as an archive or catalog of some sort. For some reason, past the “The Good Live” release, other releases just cease to load. Also, a quick clarification: “Good Life - August 18” is a different release than “The Good Live”.

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Cover</th>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>Audio</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><img src="geezer.jpg" width=300></td>
        <td>Geezer
        <li>Recorded:<ul>December 4, 1994 in New Britain, CT</ul></li>
        <li>Released: 1995</li>
        <li>Label: Kiwi Records</li>
        <li>Formats: CD</li></td>
        <td><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wrUz9MIdMZM" width="300" height="200"></iframe></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><img src="rockcandy.jpg" width=300><br><br><img src="boysatplay.jpg" width=300></td>
        <td>Rock Candy/Boys At Play
        <li>Recorded:<ul>September 9, 1994, in Minneapolis, MN</ul></li>
        <li>Released: 1995</li>
        <li>Label: Home Records/Troll Records</li>
        <li>Formats: CD</li></td>
        <td><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TKE0HsabI5A" width="300" height="200"></iframe></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><img src="americanholiday.jpg" width=300></td>
        <td>Geezer
        <li>Recorded:<ul>August 31, 1994 in St. Louis, MO <br> December 5, 1994 in New York City, NY</ul></li>
        <li>Released: 1995</li>
        <li>Label: Tornado</li>
        <li>Formats: 2xCD</li></td>
        <td><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t_n42QjQi30" width="300" height="200"></iframe><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SfXDFsJS8HI" width="300" height="200"></iframe></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><img src="goodlifeboot.jpg" width=300></td>
        <td>Good Life - Germany Aug. 18
        <li>Recorded:<ul>August 17, 1996 in Colonge, Germany (erroneously listed as August 18)<br> (unknown date in Japan)</ul></li>
        <li>Released: 1996</li>
        <li>Label: Unknown</li>
        <li>Formats: CD</li></td>
        <td>N/A</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><img src="bsidesandrarities.jpg" width=300></td>
        <td>B-sides and Rarities
        <li>Recorded:<ul>Various</ul></li>
        <li>Released: 1996</li>
        <li>Label: Loose Dog</li>
        <li>Formats: CD</li></td>
        <td>N/A</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><img src="mynameisweezer.jpg" width=300></td>
        <td>My Name Is Weezer
        <li>Recorded:<ul>November 6, 1996 in Seattle, WA<br>May 21, 1997 in Seattle, WA<br>August 18, 1996 in Saint-Malo, France</ul></li>
        <li>Released: 1997</li>
        <li>Label: Expire</li>
        <li>Formats: CD</li></td>
        <td>N/A</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><img src="goodlive.jpg" width=300></td>
        <td>The Good Live
        <li>Recorded:<ul>October 19, 1996 in Osaka, Japan</ul></li>
        <li>Released: 1999</li>
        <li>Label: Trade Mark of Quality</li>
        <li>Formats: CD</li></td>
        <td><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-TXFIh8e4Go" width="300" height="200"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><img src="splashclub.jpg" width=300></td>
        <td>Splash Club 1995
        <li>Recorded:<ul>January 30, 1995 in London, UK</ul></li>
        <li>Released: 1999</li>
        <li>Label: Unknown</li>
        <li>Formats: CD</li></td>
        <td>N/A</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><img src="londonunderworld.jpg" width=300></td>
        <td>London Underworld
        <li>Recorded:<ul>February 26, 1995 in London, UK</ul></li>
        <li>Released: 1999</li>
        <li>Label: Trade Mark of Quality</li>
        <li>Formats: CD</li></td>
        <td><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9LS0RlnZZXk" width="300" height="200"></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to close your `iframe`. Add a `</iframe>` tag just before the `</td>`. Do that for all your `iframe`'s.

Comment: i did all of that, and i don't think anything changed.

Comment: wait, nevermind, it did work, my preview just didn't update. thanks for the help!

Comment: Please [validate your HTML](https://html5.validator.nu/). There are several mistakes in your HTML structure.